# What parameter in Cytoscape determines the stacking order of edge rendering?

Tags: rendering, cytoscape

I have created a cytoscape network with a number of crossing and re-crossing edges. It is meant to do this, and I don't wish to reduce the amount of crossing that is occurring.

I would, however, like to be able to determine which edges are on "top" and which are in "back" - in the same way that you would "bring to front" or "send to back" in Powerpoint or Photoshop or any of numerous display programs.

Which style parameter or similar value is used to determine rendering order of edges? Note that I am referring to the edge line itself, and not some annotation.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that isn't available in the current release, but Cytoscape 3.9 will include that feature.  If you want to try a copy of 3.9 (which isn't nearly ready for production release), you can download it at: https://cytoscape-builds.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-builds/Cytoscape-3.9.0/

-- scooter